# Applying Coulomb's law to find the field strength at a point which is not between the two charges involved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, charge, coulombs-law

In most of the questions I encountered, I used the coulombs law only to find the force on a particle positioned between two charges. For the question below, I was not sure whether to multiply the charges,  or to use their vector sum to find the charge at P and then find the force accordingly. I tried both methods and got the wrong answer, so I have attached my working below the question. The answer is B , but I dont know how to reach it. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The vectorial sum of the two is the correct answer.

$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{3}{x^2} + \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{-4}{(2x)^2} $

= $\frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon_0 x^2}$

Comment: Thank you! I had messed up the distances amongst other mistakes  Appreciate your help!